# Google chart line with zoom and select event

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, dom-events, zooming

I built a line chart that fire an alert when the points are clicked, that works fine.

The problem is when I add the 'explorer' option (commented line, below) to enable the scroll zoom on the chart: the `select` event doesn't fire and the click doesn't work anymore ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/seurolandolero/grL4xvtj/2/))...

```
    options = {
      legend: 'none',
      format: 'none',
      hAxis: { textPosition: 'none', gridlines: { count: 0 } },
      vAxis: { textPosition: 'none', gridlines: { count: 1 } }, 
      curveType: 'function',
      pointSize: 20,
      
     
    };

    chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));        
   
   //If I enable this line, ZOOM works fine but the 'select' event don't work....
   //options['explorer'] = {axis: 'horizontal',keepInBounds: true,maxZoomIn: 5.0};        
   
   chart.draw(data_estruturas, options);
   
    //select event
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function(e) {
      var selection = chart.getSelection();     
      if (selection.length > 0) {
        var estrutura = data_estruturas.getValue(selection[0].row, 0)
        alert(estrutura);
      }
    });


}
```

Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/seurolandolero/grL4xvtj/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the draw method after register the select event.

```
//select event
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function(e) {
  var selection = chart.getSelection();     
  if (selection.length > 0) {
    var estrutura = data_estruturas.getValue(selection[0].row, 0)
    alert(estrutura);
  }
});

//After set all options and register events draw the chart
chart.draw(data_estruturas, options);
```

[I updated your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/grL4xvtj/4/)